# Invalid character Issue in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below Javascript function

```
function readMore(details) {    
  let dots = document.querySelector(`.notificationCard[data-details="${details}"] .notificationDots`);
}
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox but IE11 is throwing an invalid character error for `. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: No version of IE supports template literals. You will need to use classic string concatenation if you need this to work in IE

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20literals — better yet, _use_ template literals to "encourage" people to _stop using" IE. IE is dead. (I know, , "I have to support IE, my company uses it")